# Next.js catchall route

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I created a next.js project with the default library command, and renamed the example file `page.tsx` as `[...path].js`. According to the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes), this should catch all routes, but it doesn't.

The app is exactly the default one created by the library command `npx create-next-app@latest`.

I've tried moving the catchall file to a directory called "pages" in the root directory, creating the "pages" folder inside the "app" directory, and just moving it to that directory directly without a "pages" directory.

How are you supposed to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that is confusing everybody in the NextJS world! In the new version of NextJS, a new file-based routing system has been introduced called **app router**. Before that, we were using the **pages** router. Differences are their layout systems, API route implementations, and rendering patterns.

To have a catch-all route in the **app** router, you must use the `[...path]` name convention on the folder's name, NOT the .js file's name, so it would be like this: `/app/[...path]/page.js`. You can find more information in the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-segments).

But if you want the pages router (not recommended in version 13 anymore), you can do just like what you already did: `/pages/[...path].js`.

I hope that helps. Feel free to ask if you need more explanation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to catch the "/" route. How do I get it to catch that route?

Comment: @Test `/app/page.js`

Comment: or `/app/[[...path]]/page.js` if you want to do it with catch-all segments

Comment: hey @Arashjahanbakhshan, that worked for me exactly how I needed it. would you mind explaining the logic behind it? I understand that [...path] targets all nested routes but why does wrapping it with another set of brackets also targets the root path? thanks in advance!

Comment: @SKOLZ I'm happy I helped. there isn't any magical logic behind it. it's just a hard-coded logic which handles both root and nested dynamic routes. NextJS has built this for exactly this use-case. more information can be found in the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-segments